# TimePicker only valid if today or in future

Tags: android, validation, date, time, datetimepicker

I have a datepicker and a timepicker shown below. I am trying to validate correctly based on the current date and current time. For time, the user cannot pick a time below the current system time however I dont know how to use this in conjunction with the datepicker.

e.g. If the user picks a date in the future, but picks a time, lets say 18.00 and the system time is 19.00, A toast will currently print saying the time chosen is invalid. This is because I dont know how to check if the date set or chosen is in the past. Any ideas how to do this?

Here is my time picker which currently fails for the case above

```
public void setTimeReminder() {

    etSetTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get current time
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            final int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            final int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(editTaskForm.this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,
                                int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {



                            // select valid time check
                            if (selectedHour < hour || selectedHour == hour
                                    && selectedMinute < minute ) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Time is not valid",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } else {

                                // Select and format Time correctly

                                if (selectedHour < 10) {
                                    if (selectedMinute < 10) {
                                        time = "0" + selectedHour + ":"
                                                + "0" + selectedMinute;
                                        etSetTime.setText(time);
                                    } else {
                                        time = "0" + selectedHour + ":"
                                                + selectedMinute;
                                        etSetTime.setText(time);
                                    }

                                }

                                else {
                                    if (selectedMinute < 10) {
                                        time = selectedHour + ":" + "0"
                                                + selectedMinute;
                                        etSetTime.setText(time);
                                    } else {
                                        time = selectedHour + ":"
                                                + selectedMinute;
                                        etSetTime.setText(time);
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, hour, minute, true);// Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();

        }

    });

}
```

and date picker picker class

```
public class StartDatePicker extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int startYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int startMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int startDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
                startYear, startMonth, startDay);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

        calendarPicked = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendarPicked.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendarPicked.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        calendarPicked.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        if (calendarPicked.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            DialogFragment dialogFragment = new StartDatePicker();
            dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    "start_date_picker");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select Valid Date",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            // store date

            // values used to load into location form if needed
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put("Day", dayOfMonth);
            values.put("Month", monthOfYear);
            values.put("Year", year);

            // date to be displayed to user
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
            // date to be stored in database
            SimpleDateFormat actualDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            // to be displayed to user
            Date dateV = c.getTime();
            // to be stored in database
            Date actualD = c.getTime();

            // displayed to user
            String dateString = sdf.format(dateV);
            // stored in database
            actualDateStored = actualDate.format(actualD);

            // storing the actual date in the database***

            date = actualDateStored;

            // display day and date to user
            SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
            String dayShort = outFormat.format(dateV);
            String dateOutput = dateString;
            dateDisplayed = dayShort + " , " + dateOutput;
            etSetDate.setText(dateDisplayed);

        }

    }

}
```